# Car key got wet and is broken how do i start my car

Tags: toyota, camry, smartkey

My car key for my Toyota Camry was accidentally put through the washing machine and now no longer works. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say but you've probably fried the electronics in the key.

If you haven't already I recommend taking the fob apart (i.e. removing the battery) and placing it in a bag of rice for 24-48 hours to ensure it is fully dried out, you can then reassemble with a fresh battery and attempt to [reprogram the fob to the car](https://itstillruns.com/program-toyota-camry-remote-5755049.html), if this doesn't work then the fob is likely toast and you'll need to replace it. You can either go through a main dealer to get a new one and have them code it to the car (this is likely to be rather expensive I'm afraid) or you can try buying a replacement off eBay or similar and try programming it yourself using the steps in the above link.